# Force deleting partition and create an unallocated one

Tags: partitioning, delete

I'd like to force deleting a partition even if it is dangerous for the OS and recreate a smaller allocated partition. I install Ubuntu this morning, so it is not really important.

Could anyone explain to me how to do that?

Comment: If you have the install DVD or USB drive, you can boot from that again and run `gnome-disks`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Could you explain in more details what do you mean?

Comment: You can boot from the installer, choose to try without installing, open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, and run `gnome-disks`. Then you can edit the partitions as you'd like.

Comment: Ok, It was a good day I worked on a certain problem. This solution resolve that problem. If you write a full answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you recently installed, the easiest way is to:

1. Boot from your install DVD or USB drive
2. Choose to try Ubuntu without installing
3. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Run `gnome-disks`
5. Edit the partitions as you like

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be `Gparted`.

`sudo apt-get install gparted`. You will be asked for the password as it requires sudo privileges, if it is ran as regular user.

Also, if your partition is mounted (you can check with `mount | grep /home` )
you need to umount it first  `umount  /home`.

Or via Gparted: **Right click on partition/ Unmount**

Comment: I know all that, but you can't force to delete a partition with Gparted.